# Running a command using puppet only if it has not been executed earlier

Tags: puppet

Suppose I want to make sure that my VM has devstack on it.

```
exec{ "openstack":
  command => "git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack",
}
```

This is the puppet code I write for it and it works fine for the first time. Now I want to put a check. I want to clone the repository only if it has not been done already. How to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say

```puppet
exec { 'openstack':
  command => 'git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack',
  creates => '/path/to/somewhere/devstack',
  cwd     => '/path/to/somewhere',
  path    => '/usr/bin',
}
```

Now if the directory `/path/to/somewhere/devstack` exists the clone command won't run.

Comment: I always forget about `creates`, but then again, i dont use execs for dir or file creation often.

Comment: You can also use `-C` on `git` to remove the `cwd` attribute. This is the only one of the two answers which would clone to the desired directory too.

Comment: Actually @ptierno's solution also checks out to the desired directory.  Probably the best solution is a combination of my answer and his answer.

Comment: @AlexHarvey or using the vcsrepo module ;)

Comment: I think there are cases where an exec is simpler and preferable to a Forge module, but sure, the VCS repo is often the "Right Way".

Answer (score 4):

```
exec { "openstack":
  command => 'git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack /path/to/devstack",
  unless => 'test -d /path/to/devstack'
}
```

its a really hacky way to handle this. you should look into the vcsrepo puppet module https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you suggest some good tutorials, websites or books to learn puppet? The documentation is too confusing.

Comment: to be honest. Alex Harvey had a better answer to your problem when it comes to using the exec resource. I still feel however that the `vcsrepo` resource might be better suited.